# Building custom Erlang debian package from source files

Tags: erlang, debian-packaging

I'm trying to create Debian package from source files, but I'm stuck.
What I want to achieve:

- Download Erlang source (https://erlang.org/download/otp_src_23.1.tar.gz)
- Create the Debian package from it with configure option "--enable-fips"
- Be able to install that package on other machines

Is there any simple solution for a case like this?

Comment: I would take debian config from debain maintainer site, like https://packages.debian.org/sid/erlang-base `[erlang_23.2.1+dfsg-1.debian.tar.xz]`, then changed configure flags in `rules` and build package with `debuild` (https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/build.en.html#debuild)